# Python lib for publishing email to web

Tags: python, email

I want to read email and publish it to the web. Is there a good python library available to read email, understand headers, data, attachments etc. and which can easily convert this data to web publishable format?

Answer (score 0):

Try python [email](http://docs.python.org/library/email) module

This [tutorial](http://www.devshed.com/c/a/Python/Python-Email-Libraries-SMTP-and-Email-Parsing/) will also be helpful.

Comment: This is only for email parsing. I need something more powerful which can convert this to a web compatible format.

Comment: you mean like something that can do all the display code for you? why not parse and then write your own display code?

Comment: I could. Just checking if there is something out there, so i do not end up reinventing the wheel.

Comment: what do you mean "web compatible format"? once you parse the email it is in "web compatible format", now it is upto you how you want to display it? or you just want a tool which will publish emails?